# Why does setting the bitrate with ffmpeg has no affect on the filesize?

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to lower the bitrate of a video using ffmpeg to 1000 bits/s and 500 bits/s using the commands

```
ffmpeg -i __temp__.mp4  -vf "scale=-2:360" -b:v 1000 out_1000.ts
ffmpeg -i __temp__.mp4  -vf "scale=-2:360" -b:v 500 out_500.ts
```

but the output files seem to have the same size:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 alex alex 8160140 Nov  2 13:11 out_1000.ts
-rw-rw-r-- 1 alex alex 8160140 Nov  2 13:11 out_500.ts
```

- Size of original video: 8344903
- Framerate: 15 fps

What is going on?

Comment: 1000 bits/s is absurdly low - maybe not even enough to form all the syntax elements of a coded bitstream. Maybe you meant `1000k`.

Comment: Yes I know it is low. I meant 1000, not 1000k.